# Suppress certain Windows keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I'm attempting to suppress some Windows keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>LWIN</kbd>/<kbd>RWIN</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) so my application can handle them elsehow (simulating keypresses on an external machine).

According to other SO questions and answers this is supposed to work:

```
        this.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => {
            if (e.Key == Key.LWin || e.Key == Key.RWin)
                e.Handled = true;
        };
```

Problem is, it doesn't work. Whenever I hit <kbd>LWIN</kbd>/<kbd>RWIN</kbd>, the Start menu still pops up which I want to suppress so my application alone can use it. In the above snippet, `this` refers to a WPF Window which was being focussed while testing this. (It should obviously only suppress the action once Window has focus.)

Any way to achieve what I'd like to achieve?

Thanks,

~Tgys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *Hook* all the *Keyboard* and even *Mouse* events to detect the source of input. In other words, if you use the *Global Hook* as mentioned in the link below, you can capture system events and either process them like normal events or suppress them.

You should have a look at this *CodeProject* article, [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A *global hook* monitors messages for all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread. A *thread-specific hook* monitors messages for only an individual thread. A global hook procedure can be called in the context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread, so the procedure must be in a separate DLL module. A thread-specific hook procedure is called only in the context of the associated thread.

**C# Code:**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }

    //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

    //Declaring Global objects
    private IntPtr ptrHook;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

    private IntPtr CaptureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin) // Disabling Windows keys
            {
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Get Current Module
        ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        //Assign callback function each time keyboard process
        objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(CaptureKey);
        //Setting Hook of Keyboard Process for current module
        ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0); 
    }
}
```

Other Good References:

1. [Low-level Windows API hooks from C# to stop unwanted keystrokes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante)
2. [Disable Special Keys in Win App C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx)

Comment: The first article that you mention, now has a [CodePlex Site](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) where you can download the library.