# How to prevent Windows+D key combination Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to prevent key combinations Window+D using xaml.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="F10" Command="{Binding CommandAltF10}"></KeyBinding>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Windows" Key="D" Command="{Binding CommandWindowD}"></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The first combination is working. When I press `Alt+F10` keys, `CommandAltf10` command is firing.

But when I press the `Window+D` keys, it does not fire `CommandWindowD` command. Why does not it work?

Comment: That combination is usually already registered to minimize all windows and show the desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress certain Windows keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324059/suppress-certain-windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey): *Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system* so you can't use the native `RegisterHotKey` API to override these and even less a `KeyBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: [Capture a keyboard keypress in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background)

NOTE: It is impossible to handle this in XAML you need to create a global hotkey

I edited the solution to fit your needs:

1. Import needed libraries at the top of your class:

```
// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
//Add a field in your class that will be a reference for the hotkey in your code:
const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
```

2. Register the hotkey (in the constructor of your Window for instance):

```
// Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
// Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
// WIN KEY: 8 see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 8, (int) Keys.D);
```

3. Handle the typed keys by adding the following method in your class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID) {
        // My hotkey has been typed
        // in your case you want to return in order to not trigger the event
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```